# ConverterNotFoundException when call ConvertionService inside Converter implementaion

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to convert entity to DTO using spring Convertion Service. Maybe the problem is that I call ConversionService inside my implementation of Converter.
This is my converter :

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ResourceToGroupFilterResourcesCardDtoConverter implements Converter<Resource, GroupFilterResourcesCardDto> {

    private final ConversionService conversionService;

    @Override
    public GroupFilterResourcesCardDto convert(Resource source) {
        return GroupFilterResourcesCardDto.builder()
                .uuid(source.getUuid())
                .primarySoftware(source.getPrimarySoftware() != null ? source.getPrimarySoftware().stream()
                        .map(it->conversionService.convert(it, PrimarySoftwareDto.class))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()) : null)
                .build();
    }
```

I have a lot of over converters like that, but this one can't be found when I call ConversionService

This is the place where I try to call it:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class ResourceListToGroupFilterResourceCatalogDtoMapper {

    private final ConversionService conversionService;

    public GroupFilterResourcesCatalogDto convert(List<Resource> resources) {
        if (resources == null || resources.isEmpty()) {
            return GroupFilterResourcesCatalogDto.builder().resources(List.of()).build();
        }
        return GroupFilterResourcesCatalogDto.builder()
                .resources(resources.stream()
                                   .map(it -> conversionService.convert(it, GroupFilterResourcesCardDto.class))
                                   .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .build();
    }
```

In fact I got this exception:

```
2022-02-11 15:12:25.554 ERROR 12028 --- [nio-7044-exec-6] r.i.s.c.error.GlobalExceptionHandler     : Error id=e43b0d60-c419-4889-82a7-d356b6011d0c with message:

org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [ru.khloptsev.back.model.entity.resource.Resource] to type [ru.khloptsev.back.model.domain.back.filter.response.GroupFilterResourcesCardDto]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:321)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:194)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:174)
    at ru.khloptsev.back.mapper.filter.ResourceListToGroupFilterResourceCatalogDtoMapper.lambda$convert$0(ResourceListToGroupFilterResourceCatalogDtoMapper.java:33)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at ru.khloptsev.back.mapper.filter.ResourceListToGroupFilterResourceCatalogDtoMapper.convert(ResourceListToGroupFilterResourceCatalogDtoMapper.java:34)
    at ru.khloptsev.back.facade.filter.FilterFacadeImpl.getResources(FilterFacadeImpl.java:171)
    at ru.khloptsev.back.facade.filter.FilterFacadeImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$709444d5.invoke(<generated>)
```

When I try to debug and look at conversionService, I see that it Has a lot of converters, but not mine. At converterCache there is a key for my converter with NO_MATCH value.

Thank you